# SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes

Tags: mysql, laravel

Getting an error after submiting "php artisan migrate:fresh" in cmd.

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->string('email')->unique();
            $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
}
```

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes (SQL: alter table `users` add unique `users_email_unique`(`email`))

Comment: may helps : https://laravel-news.com/laravel-5-4-key-too-long-error

Comment: Yes, anyone can easily find that link with Google. The problem is that the link is explaining an ugly workaround for legacy code. When you run into this error with an up-to-date Laravel project, this link just tells you how to hobble your code to avoid fixing the DB server.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

From this link: https://laravel-news.com/laravel-5-4-key-too-long-error

> For those running MariaDB or older versions of MySQL you may hit this
> error when trying to run migrations
>
> As outlined in the Migrations guide to fix this all you have to do is
> edit your AppServiceProvider.php file and inside the boot method set a
> default string length:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

public function boot()
{
    Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
}
```

> After that everything should work as normal.

Please note that as per Andrew Koster's comment below it's possible this is only a solution intended for legacy code. You may wish to look into different solutions for up-to-date projects.

Comment: i really think without looking that this is the most visited laravel-news article :D

Comment: Well it's concise, useful and addresses a version upgrade problem. So it probably ranks decently high.

Comment: What are the downside of this?

Comment: It's only useful for legacy code. For any up-to-date Laravel project, it's a way to create problems down the road when you could just fix your outdated DB instead.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT: FYI ... v4 of this package, which adds some unique indexes in the migration, requires 125 instead of 191 if you're using MySQL 8.0. (MariaDB doesn't require any of this).

Answer (score 0):

According to the official `Laravel 7.x` documentation, you can solve this quite easily.

Update your `/app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php` file to contain:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;

/**
 * Bootstrap any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    Schema::defaultStringLength(191);
}
```